# str_to_date change year data MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, str-to-date

I am trying to change the format of my date which is `mm/dd/yyyy` to MySQL format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

But it changes the data year to `2020`.

The `product_history` table:

```
log_date    id      stock
10/30/2018  1001    59    
10/30/2018  1002    35   
10/30/2018  1003    54    
10/30/2018  1004    40   
10/30/2018  1005    5     
10/30/2018  1006    20   
10/30/2018  1007    69   
...
```

This is my code:

```
SELECT *, str_to_date(my_schema.product_history.log_date, '%m/%d/%y') as new_log_date FROM my_schema.product_history
```

Output:

```
log_date    id      stock new_log_date
10/30/2018  1001    59    2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1002    35    2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1003    54    2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1004    40    2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1005    5     2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1006    20    2020-10-30
10/30/2018  1007    69    2020-10-30
...
```

Comment: what is the output of `my_schema.product_history.log_date`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%y` represents a year in two digits. Since you have four digits, you should use `%Y` instead:

```sql
SELECT *, str_to_date(my_schema.product_history.log_date, '%m/%d/%Y') AS new_log_date 
-- Here ----------------------------------------------------------^
FROM   my_schema.product_history
```

Comment: Thanks. By changing `%y` to `%Y`, the year data is correct.